# gstreamer: record and playback with ffenc_g726/ffdec_g726

Tags: gstreamer

With gstreamer, I am trying to record audio in g726(adpcm) audio format and then play it back later.
I have tried following:
For recording:
`gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! ffenc_g726 rate=16000 ! filesink location="recg726.wav"`

And then, later on, I have tried to playback this `recg726.wav` recorded file but I am getting following error:
`"Could not determine type of stream"`

It look like the g726 recorded file does not have a good header format.

Is Anybody can help here?

Here is the playback gstreamer command (i have tried both `"playbin"` the generic playback binary and also the `ffdec_g726` plugin):

```
gst-launch playbin uri=file:///home/root/recg726.wav
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind: Could not determine type of stream.
```

Comment: You might need to put `! wavenc` in front of `filesink`. I also suspect, as g726 sampling frequency is fixed to 8 kHz, you need to put `audioconvert ! audioresample ` in front of ffenc_g726.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on putting ! wavenc in front of filesink but I got following error: erroneous pipeline: could not link ffenc_g7260 to wavenc0" and it exit: gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! ffenc_g726 ! wavenc ! filesink location="recg726.wav"

Answer (score 0):

The WAV format uses "raw" 16bit integer samples, not G.726 encoded audio. If you want to make a WAV file, use wavenc as your encoder, not G.726: `gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! wavenc ! filesink location="rec.wav"` (Why would you want to use G.726 anyway?)